# Kick off CRON JOB and send the back end data automatically to several JSPS

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, controller, spring-restcontroller

I searched all over but was unable to find a suitable answer, and hence posting this question.

I have a spring boot application that needs to be scheduled through a cron job to run every hour and fetch data from a web site. I split the list into 5 groups. I need to push the list data into 5 different jsp's (automatically update it every hour).
for example -->
groupList1 to group1.jsp
groupList2 to group2.jsp
groupList3 to group3.jsp

groupList4 to group4.jsp

groupList5 to group5.jsp

I am unable to find information where the data can be pushed to several screens without having to click the submit button. So set up something in the controller to push it to the front end.

I am new to JSP's and hence would like some advice on this.

I am using a Tomcat server, Eclipse 4.25 Java 11 and springboot.
Thanks.

The CRON job, web service works fine. Have split it into 5 groups,

I am able to make the front end work if I have a jsp page with a form and a submit button, calls the controller,-->  back end service --> controller (postmapping) --> JSP.

I am unable to figure out a way to automate it to:
cron job --> controller --> web service --> controller --> display on 5 seperate JSP pages. I am unable to figure out the post mapping that has to be done from controller to JSP.

Comment: Can we run both Java 1.8 and Java 11 on the same tomcat server machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding a timer to the java script which refreshed the page every few hours.

This question can be closed/marked as answered.